# adobe phonegap Google Maps not displaying

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I have a an app I wrote in javascript and html and I am trying to import it into adobe phone gap to make an android app. My config.xml looks liek this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="net.seekadventure" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>HelloCordova</name>
  <description>
      Test of Adobe apache
  </description>
  <author email="hidden" href="hidden">
      Seek ADventure Team
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />

  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
      <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
</widget>
```

When I install my app My google map shows very quickly for a quick instant and then it disappears and says:

"Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load google maps correctly. See the javascript console for technical details."

unfortunately, I am not sure how to view the javascript console since it's now in an android app on my phone. The code works fine on my webserver... Not sure what the issue is here or where to start looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my issue. My Google map api key was limited to only work on my domain for my website. So within the app it would not work!